# Producing all permutations for a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, permutation

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':['TP53', 'COX5', 'P16'], 'test':[1,3,0], 'Healthy':[0,0,2]})

    Gene    test    Healthy
0   TP53    1       0
1   COX5    3       0
2   P16     0       2
```

I have been trying to create a permutation of all possible values.
The idea is to map the first gene "TP53" and it's value in column "test" to every other gene and record the value of the "Healthy" column.

For example, initially TP53 would be mapped to itself: TP53:TP53:1:0
Then TP53 would be mapped to COX5 from the Healthy column: TP53:COX5:1:0
Followed by the next gene: TP53:P16:1:2
Next the gene COX5 would be mapped using the value in the "test" column to compare against the "Healthy" column: COX5:TP53:3:0
then: COX5:COX5:3:0

So eventually the following table would be produced:

```
All_combinations
TP53:TP53:1:0
TP53:COX5:1:0
TP53:P16:1:2
COX5:TP53:3:0
COX5:COX5:3:0
COX5:P16:3:2
P16:TP53:0:0
P16:COX5:0:0
P16:P16:0:2
```

I have tried the following code but am having difficulty.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':['TP53', 'COX5', 'P16'], 'test':[1,3,0], 'Healthy':[0,0,2]})
df2 = df1.transpose()
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2.iloc[1:]

from itertools import product
uniques = [df1[i].unique().tolist() for i in df1.iloc[:,[1,2]]]
pd.DataFrame(product(*uniques), columns = df2.iloc[:,])
```

The real data set has over 32,000 rows so something that works fast would be great.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"Having difficulty" is not a problem specification.

Comment: You realize that all pair-wise combinations of 32,000 rows will give you a data frame that has over 1 billion rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code solve your problem?

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':['TP53', 'COX5', 'P16'], 'test':[1,3,0], 'Healthy':[0,0,2]})

# Create all the combinations as tuples. 
# Note that test is taken from gene1 but Healthy from gene2
# The enumerate is used to get the row number related to that gene
row_list = []
for i, gene1 in enumerate(df1.Gene):
    for j, gene2 in enumerate(df1.Gene):
        row_list.append((gene1, gene2, df1.iloc[i].test, df1.iloc[j].Healthy))

# Now create a new dataframe with the results
df2 = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=['Gene1', 'Gene2', 'test', 'Healthy'])
```

This produces:

```
  Gene1 Gene2  test  Healthy
0  TP53  TP53     1        0
1  TP53  COX5     1        0
2  TP53   P16     1        2
3  COX5  TP53     3        0
4  COX5  COX5     3        0
5  COX5   P16     3        2
6   P16  TP53     0        0
7   P16  COX5     0        0
8   P16   P16     0        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since already a `pandas` solution is given. Just showing how `product` works

```
a=[1,3,0]
b=[0,0,2]
from itertools import product
list(product(*[a]+[b]))

[(1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (3, 0), (3, 0), (3, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 2)]
```